# Don't get `should validate_inclusion_of` to work in Rails3.2, RSpec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :gender, :inclusion => { :in => ['male', 'female'] }
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "contacts", :force => true do |t|
      t.string  "gender",  :limit => 6, :default => 'male'
    end
  end
end
```

RSpec test:

```
describe Contact do
  it { should validate_inclusion_of(:gender).in(['male', 'female']) }
end
```

Result:

```
Expected Contact to be valid when gender is set to ["male", "female"]
```

Anybody has an idea why this spec doesn't pass? Or can anybody reconstruct and (in)validate it? Thank you.

Comment: which of the various gems that add a validate_inclusion_of matcher are you using?

Comment: Oh, there are several of them? I use the Remarkable Gem:

    gem 'remarkable', '>=4.0.0.alpha2'
    gem 'remarkable_activemodel', '>=4.0.0.alpha2'
    gem 'remarkable_activerecord', '>=4.0.0.alpha2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood how the `.in(..)` should be used. I thought I could pass an array of values, but it seems it does only accept a single value:

```
describe Contact do
  ['male', 'female'].each do |gender|
    it { should validate_inclusion_of(:gender).in(gender) }
  end
end
```

I don't really know what's the difference to using `allow_value` though:

```
['male', 'female'].each do |gender|
  it { should allow_value(gender).for(:gender) }
end
```

And I guess it's always a good idea to check for some not allowed values, too:

[:no, :valid, :gender].each do |gender|
    it { should_not validate_inclusion_of(:gender).in(gender) }
  end

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to test these things directly. Example:

```
%w!male female!.each do |gender|
  it "should validate inclusion of #{gender}" do
    model = Model.new(:gender => gender)
    model.save
    model.errors[:gender].should be_blank
  end
end

%w!foo bar!.each do |gender|
  it "should validate inclusion of #{gender}" do
    model = Model.new(:gender => gender)
    model.save
    model.errors[:gender].should_not be_blank
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful snippet. Still I'd like to have the matcher working...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in_array`

From the docs:

```
  # The `validate_inclusion_of` matcher tests usage of the
  # `validates_inclusion_of` validation, asserting that an attribute can
  # take a whitelist of values and cannot take values outside of this list.
  #
  # If your whitelist is an array of values, use `in_array`:
  #
  #     class Issue
  #       include ActiveModel::Model
  #       attr_accessor :state
  #
  #       validates_inclusion_of :state, in: %w(open resolved unresolved)
  #     end
  #
  #     # RSpec
  #     describe Issue do
  #       it do
  #         should validate_inclusion_of(:state).
  #           in_array(%w(open resolved unresolved))
  #       end
  #     end
  #
  #     # Test::Unit
  #     class IssueTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  #       should validate_inclusion_of(:state).
  #         in_array(%w(open resolved unresolved))
  #     end
  #
  # If your whitelist is a range of values, use `in_range`:
  #
  #     class Issue
  #       include ActiveModel::Model
  #       attr_accessor :priority
  #
  #       validates_inclusion_of :priority, in: 1..5
  #     end
  #
  #     # RSpec
  #     describe Issue do
  #       it { should validate_inclusion_of(:state).in_range(1..5) }
  #     end
  #
  #     # Test::Unit
  #     class IssueTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  #       should validate_inclusion_of(:state).in_range(1..5)
  #     end
  #
```